# Android Facebook sdk 3.5 share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, share

hi i am implementing the facebook share dialog for android sdk 3.5 however i am not getting any success im following the guides..

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MyClass.this)
                            .setApplicationName("App Name")
                            .setName("Name")
                            .setLink("mylink")
                            .build();
```

i put this inside my on touch method there are no errors appearing
but whenever i click the button.. nothing appears also~

is the MyClass.this wrong? thanks for reply~

Comment: I think you have to call `shareDialog.present();` after building it.

Comment: Also, by creating a separate `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder` object (and not chaining method calls), you can perform the check: `if (myBuilder.canPresent()) { myBuilder.build().present();`. This is what `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder.canPresent()` does: `Determines whether the native dialog can be presented (i.e., whether the required version of the Facebook application is installed on the device, and whether the installed version supports all of the parameters specified for the dialog).`

Comment: i see thanks.. ill check on that too~

Comment: is there any other way rather than present()? to show the dialog coz its too slow and it is not showing... it just lags a bit and i have log that facebook is activated but not really showing~

Comment: `is there any other way rather than present()?` That _is_ the method. Not sure if any others exist. Are you testing on a device? If not, try that.

Comment: yup on a device. no luck facebook just loads but no dialog appears =_= thx btw~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what Facebook recommends. I've just copied the code examples from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share) where it is also explained how to handle the `uiHelper` instance.

If you don't care about the results of the dialog it might be ok not to use the uiHelper.

Using the static method to check whether the dialog can be presented is prudent because it only initializes the builder and creates the dialog if it really is possible to present it.

```
if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(),
FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
    // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

} else {
    // Fallback. For example, publish the post using the Feed Dialog
    publishFeedDialog();
}
```

And this is the feed dialog fallback:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
            new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params)).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem as in the question. With simple debug I got to know that the application is not running code inside the if statement, meaning Facebook app was not found, BUT it is there. I am using lenevo model.

After going inside else statement, it should present a feed dialog as in publishFeedDialog . But even this is not shown.

Comment: I believe my app is not yet live from developers.facebook.com How can I check that?

Comment: If you dont have a session ? do you know what should you do ? i need to make people can share without having facebook app installed, also, i cant integrate facebook login in the app, i used the dialog/feed url and starting an intent action_view but i cant get back to previous app state. any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact problem, it turned out I forgot to add `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>` before the `</application>` tag in my AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this:
 This is a useful link
https://gist.github.com/jacklt/6700201