# Share text on Facebook from android app

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, share, facebook-share

Hi i need to share text from my app to Facebook i tried this code

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, DESCRIPTION);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, DESCRIPTION);
        PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        boolean resolved = false;
        for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo: resolvedInfoList){
            if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.facebook.katana")){
                sharingIntent.setClassName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, 
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name );
                resolved = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(resolved){
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
        }else{

             android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert  = new   AlertDialog.Builder(SingleItemView.this);
                alert.setTitle("Warning");
                alert.setMessage("Facebook App not found");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                alert.show();
        }
```

it opens Facebook post by installed Facebook but with blank post how can i pass my text to Facebook app ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604937/android-facebook-sdk-3-5-share-dialog

Comment: have you check DESCRIPTION value before set putExtra ?

Comment: i m with @HareshChhelana DESCRIPTION value  putExtra

Comment: @HareshChhelana and Naveen .. yes even though i tried to put simple text and also got blank post

Comment: try to comment EXTRA_SUBJECT line only pass EXTRA_TEXT.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I tried  but same :( blank post

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Now Facebook API does not support pre-filling the message for users as seen in this Policy : https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

**OR**

Check this discussion : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Facebook only allows a link to be shared. So the intent you have done is fine but try sharing a http:// link. It shares the site and allows the user to make a comment on the link they are sharing.

Comment: but how some apps posts text on the wall ?

Comment: that means we cannot share plain text using fb sdk on the wall.